# VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///dev/video0'. Check the log for details

Tags: usb, vlc-media-player, ubuntu-16.04, vlan

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with VLC 3.0.4 (Vetinari). I want to use VLC 3.0.4 with an USB camera for rendering. VLC says

> VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///dev/video0'. Check the log for detail.

Google search was a bit helpful regarding this but nothing came up.

What I tried is:

- Experiment on these links [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69314/vlc-unable-to-open-mrl-v4l2-dev-video0), [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xawtv/+bug/488455) and [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1405429).
- I have an old version of VLC (2.2.8) and the same USB camera works fine.

My video group is given as follows

```
xxxx-z3@xxxx-z3:~$ grep video /etc/group
video:x:44:xxxx-z3,vdr,root
```

usb camera is having below permission:

```
xxxx-z3@xxxx-z3:~$ ll /dev/video0 
crwsrwsrwt+ 1 root video 81, 0 Dec 27 18:40 /dev/video0
```

`lsusb` output for

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 046d:081b Logitech, Inc. Webcam C310
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 22b8:2e24 Motorola PCS 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0461:4e22 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My question is, why VLC 3.0.4 is unable to open `/dev/video0` device?

Logs from VLC with debug message level 2.

Logs from vlc message with debug level 2:

> qt debug: item v4l2-dev
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-vbidev
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-chroma
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-input
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-audio-input
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-width
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-height
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-aspect-ratio
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-fps
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-radio-dev
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-tuner-frequency
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-tuner-audio-mode
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-controls-reset
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-brightness
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-brightness-auto
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-contrast
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-saturation
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-hue
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-hue-auto
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-white-balance-temperature
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-auto-white-balance
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-red-balance
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-blue-balance
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-gamma
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-autogain
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-gain
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-sharpness
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-chroma-gain
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-chroma-gain-auto
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-power-line-frequency
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-backlight-compensation
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-band-stop-filter
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-hflip
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-vflip
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-rotate
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-color-killer
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-color-effect
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-audio-volume
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-audio-balance
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-audio-mute
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-audio-bass
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-audio-treble
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-audio-loudness
>
> qt debug: item v4l2-set-ctrls
>
> main debug: processing request item: v4l2:///dev/video1, node: Playlist, skip: 0
>
> main debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
>
> main debug: rebuild done - 1 items, index 0
>
> main debug: starting playback of new item
>
> main debug: resyncing on v4l2:///dev/video1
>
> main debug: v4l2:///dev/video1 is at 0
>
> main debug: creating new input thread
>
> main debug: Creating an input for 'v4l2:///dev/video1'
>
> main debug: requesting art for new input thread
>
> main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
>
> main debug: using default timeshift path
>
> main debug: `v4l2:///dev/video1' gives access`v4l2' demux `any' path`/dev/video1'
>
> main debug: creating demux: access='v4l2' demux='any' location='/dev/video1' file='/dev/video1'
>
> main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "v4l2": 21 candidates
>
> v4l2 debug: opening device '/dev/video1'
>
> v4l2 error: cannot open device '/dev/video1': Operation not permitted
>
> v4l2 debug: opening device '/dev/video1'
>
> v4l2 error: cannot open device '/dev/video1': Operation not permitted
>
> main debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
>
> main debug: no access_demux modules matched
>
> main debug: creating access: v4l2:///dev/video1
>
> lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/vijay/snap/vlc/768/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
>
> main debug: (path: /dev/video1)
>
> main debug: looking for access module matching "v4l2": 26 candidates
>
> lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /snap/vlc/768/usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
>
> lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /snap/vlc/768/usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
>
> v4l2 debug: opening device '/dev/video1'
>
> main debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
>
> v4l2 error: cannot open device '/dev/video1': Operation not permitted
>
> main debug: no access modules matched
>
> main debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
>
> main debug: dead input
>
> main debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
>
> main debug: nothing to play
>
> lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/vijay/snap/vlc/768/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
>
> lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /snap/vlc/768/usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art
>
> lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /snap/vlc/768/usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
>
> lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /snap/vlc/768/usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
>
> lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /snap/vlc/768/usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
>
> lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /snap/vlc/768/usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/01_googleimage.luac
>
> lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /snap/vlc/768/usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
>
> lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /snap/vlc/768/usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/02_frenchtv.luac
>
> lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script /snap/vlc/768/usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
>
> lua debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) /snap/vlc/768/usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/art/03_lastfm.luac
>
> lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in /snap/vlc/768/usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
>
> main debug: no art finder modules matched

Comment: did you mount your device first? Is it accessible through a folder?

Comment: APOLOGIES, my comment was not useful. Check this solution out: https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Webcam-HOWTO/dev-intro.html

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly, no answer helped me so far.
In the end I managed to notice this line, in the output of `vlc --verbose 3`:

```
[019b5b98] main libvlc warning: cannot load module `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/codec/libv4l2_plugin.so' (libzvbi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

After I installed `zvbi` everything worked.

Comment: Here's a fix that worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1243550/883154

Answer (score 0):

This link explains better than i can: https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Webcam-HOWTO/dev-intro.html

Try the recreating the `video0` nod in the `/dev` directory to see if that solves your problem.

```
sudo mknod /dev/video0 c 81 0
sudo chown root:video /dev/video0
sudo chmod 660 /dev/video0
```

If you still having problem after this, try rebooting also.

`/dev` files are not-ordinary files, such as a `.txt` file, but they are interface to devices, like nodes, and most important they do not reside really on your (our) disk.

`/dev` files represent devices attached/on your computer, resident files are created run-rime.

The simplest solution to restore that file is to reboot your computer.
(when you power-off a computer, `/dev` is empty)

As an alternative, un-plug and plug the implicated device should have the same effect.

> Experimental (have no idea if this will work): file://localhost/Volumes/DATA-DISK/Media/Video0

other links:
https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/
https://itsfoss.com/vlc-pro-tricks-linux/

credit: 
[Bernard Wei](https://askubuntu.com/users/398808/bernard-wei) &
[mattia.b89](https://askubuntu.com/users/449817/mattia-b89)

> **EDIT: 12/28/18**

**/dev/video0: Permission denied**

it turns out that the error isnt a error, you will get the same response in log if you type in "asidjaisjdiajsdiasd" so what the solution to the problem is, is:

```
 $ sudo chown user.group /dev/shm/usb-*
```

**if this doesn't work, try:**

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/get-your-usb-drives-to-work-with.html

"Users and groups" is not installed by default in Ubuntu 12.04 and newer, so you'll have to install it firstly:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTMqf.jpg)

You must give to the user (you) permission for use video devices. Go to 
`System > Administration > Users and Groups`. Unlock and select your username. In user privileges, you must enable the line "Capture video from TV or webcams, and use 3d acceleration" or "Use Video Devices" log off and log in.

*the **third solution** is to define your own paths. Let me know how the new solution works. If it doesn't work, ill post the long rundown to redefining your paths.*

Comment: @ DeerSpotter, Thanks for your suggestion . Do I really need to add /dev/video0 using mknod. Because same camera device is working fine for older version of vlc 2.2.8 then it should also work for new version of vlc 3.0.4. I just want to understand where is issue.

Comment: I tried all your suggestion but nothing worked for me. Still I'm getting same message "VLC is unable to open the MRL 'v4l2:///dev/video0'."

Comment: @ChakravarthiPradeep try:https://medium.com/@petehouston/use-vlc-to-play-camera-with-different-formats-17cf839b72d0

Comment: I did it , it same as GUI. I will get same error.

Comment: My question is updated with VLC debug log message with level 2.

Comment: @ChakravarthiPradeep can you try this:

"sudo chmod 777 /dev/video0"

Comment: Could you please tell me where is this path in ubuntu 16.04              
 "System > Administration > Users and Groups" ?

Comment: @ChakravarthiPradeep (sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools) link:https://askubuntu.com/questions/66718/how-to-manage-users-and-groups-using-gui